# How to return a pdf object instead of saving using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I need to create a pdf file and send with a POST request to a server. 
For creating pdf, the code is very simple

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output("mypdf.pdf");
```

For POSTing, I read the pdf file by

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("mypdf.pdf");
```

Is there a way that I don't have to first write to file and then read back from it? 
Some way of doing

```
$file_contents = $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645034/try-to-show-pdf-file-using-php-and-fpdf

Comment: @lordkain Sorry but this doesn't work for me. On this answer user is trying to display it. Whereas I am trying to get it in the same format as it is when it's read from file. Could you please tell me how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I get the question correctly, you want the data stream?

If so, `Output()` take 2 parameters, `name and destination`. Sending `S` as destination parameter will return a `string` of the pdf data.

so, keeping your code

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$file_contents = $pdf->Output("mypdf.pdf","S");
```

[source](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: can I use this also in as return value of an ajax call?

Comment: is there any way to create this PDF directly on Azure storage?

Answer (score 3):

Per fdf [`Output()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) documentation:

```
Output([string name, string dest])
```

#### name

> The name of the file. If not specified, the document will be sent to the browser (destination I) with the name doc.pdf.

#### dest

> Destination where to send the document. It can take one of the following values:
>
> - I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
> - D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
> - F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
> - S: return the document as a string. name is ignored.

So if you want to pass the file contents to variable, use:

```
$pdf_file_contents = $pdf->Output("","S");
```