# Opening the PDF file onclick of a button with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

[image: EDITED: HERE IS WHAT IT IS RETURNING AT ALERT(DATA)]I want to open PDF File onclick of a button. I tried doing this with AJAX but it doesn't open the PDF file. 
I keep receiving this alert everything I clicked the `View PDF` button.

Here is the my code for AJAX:

```
function viewPDF(id){    
          $.ajax({  url: "viewCrf.php",
            data: {'idd' : id},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
}
```

The AJAX code above will be trigger after the clicked of this button:

```
<td><input id='$idd' 
type='button' 
value='View PDF'class='btn btn-primary' onclick='viewPDF(this.id)'
target='_blank' ></td>
```

The viewCrf.php contains the code for generating the PDF. Uses POST method to get the value passed by the AJAX then get the data from the database

```
$id = $_POST['idd'];
$q  =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM crf where col_ID = ".$id);
    while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        $last               = $r['col_ln'];
        $first              = $r['col_fn'];
        $middle             = $r['col_mi'];
        $civilstatus        = $r['col_civilstat'];
        $sex                = $r['col_gender'];
        $dob                = $r['col_bday'];             
    }
```

My problem here is that, the PDF file isn't opening at all. Though the success part on the AJAX seems to alert something when I add `alert(data)`.

This code supposedly should open a PDF file on the click of the button.

Comment: I see nothing that would open a pdf here

Comment: What is the resulting alert content of `alert(data)` ?

Comment: That's my problem D: I don't know how to open it onclick of the button.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette A long list of unknown symbols.

Comment: Is the url of your PDF file in database ? This is what your should retreive...

Comment: is your PHP file setting the proper headers? like `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`

Comment: @JerlonBuenconsejo In the HTML add a div with a specific ID. Inside `success: function (data) { }` (the curly brackets) write: `$('#yourSpecificID').html(data);` Everything will output to the div, that'll be a better way of viewing it rather than an alert. You want to use an alert for testing out a small word or phrase, not entire excel sheet. Or just console.log

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No. I didn't save it on a database. Browsers have a feature that can read pdf files and review it and download it afterwards. I only pass the id of the customer to the PDF maker via AJAX . In the PDF Maker file, which is `viewCrf.php`. Then fetch the data and put it on the PDF.

Comment: @awl19 Did that but doesn't show anything. But it alerts something like this `%PDF01.4
3 0 obj
<<Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
.
.
.`

Comment: What generates the PDF ? Is it FPDF?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes. I am using FPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Since using FPDF, you certainly have some PHP [code looking like this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm).

If you didn't specifed any aguments to `output()`, it produces inline HTML.
[Reference about the output method here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm).

So, this should work:

```
<td>
    <input id='$idd' type='button' value='View PDF'class='btn btn-primary' onclick='viewPDF(this.id)' target='_blank' >
</td>
<div id="pdfResult"></div>

<script>
function viewPDF(id){  
    $.ajax({  url: "viewCrf.php",
        data: {'idd' : id},
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#pdfResult").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Still not showing anything. I edited my post and added an image of what the alert(data) is returning.

Comment: Check the `Dest` parameter of `output()`. It is `I` by default... It looks like you specified `S`... as for "string".

Comment: I didn't put anything inside the Output(). Yet it still returning the above picture.

Comment: OK... Maybe now... This is all that is missing : `header("Content-type: application/PDF");`. Found it in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645034/try-to-show-pdf-file-using-php-and-fpdf

Comment: ! ... You'll have to show your full `viewCrf.php` code.

Comment: Anyway, I found the answer :). I just  used GET METHOD and change the button into an href.

Answer (score 0):

I change the `button` to an `href` instead and use GET METHOD.

```
<td>".$result['col_ID']."</td>
<td>".$result['col_fn']." ".$result['col_ln']."</td>
<td><a href='viewCrf.php?idd=".$idd."' type='button' 
value='View PDF'class='btn btn-primary'
target='_blank' >
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewCrf.php file, you must edit headers for say that's a PDf file ( and not show the pdf code.)

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```